# Remove all additional extensions from files

Tags: linux, bash

I have files that have any number of extensions

```
a.jpg
b.jpg.jpg
c.jpg.jpg.png
...
```

I need to remove all extensions beyond the first one

```
a.jpg
b.jpg
c.jpg
...
```

I currently have the following to find files with additional extensions

```
find . -type f -name "*.*.*"
find . -type f -name "*.*.*.*"
find . -type f -name "*.*.*.*.*"
...
```

I'm not sure how to make a cleaner version of this.  The only periods in the file names are right before the extensions so I can pick everything up to and including the first extension with regex along with -exec mv in the above find command but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Do you have any dots in the file name *before* the first extension? Such as "my.picture.jpg.jpg"?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `rename` utility then you can use:

```
rename -n 's/([^.]*\.[^.]+).+/$1/' *.*.*
```

Remove `-n` (dry run) after you are satisfied with output.

If you don't have `rename` then you may use `sed` like this:

```
for i in *.*.*; do
    echo mv "$i" "$(sed -E 's/([^.]*\.[^.]+).+/\1/' <<< "$i")"
done
```

Remove `echo` after you're satisfied with the output.

Answer (score 0):

Using only [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) with [extglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

for file in *.*.*; do
    del=${file##+([^.]).+([^.])}
    mv "$file" "${file%"$del"}"
done
```